# User Interface Using Tkinter to display a Chessboard

Tags: python, user-interface, chess

[image: code output]

So I have some basic Tkinter Code, that displays this here and in that red box there basically I want to display a Chessboard with the pieces overlaying on the Chessboard but however you can click on the pieces that will then show the available moves and i was wondering what would be the best way to display these images without making 64 different variables?

Comment: Use a 2-dimentional list

Answer (score 0):

First you need to think about how you want to represent your board. The most straightforward way is a 2D 8x8 array like this:

```
board = [['--' for x in range(8)] for x in range(8)]
```

Then you place the pieces on the correct places in this board, for example the black rook at top left corner:

```
board[0][0] = 'bR'
```

When the user clicks on a square you get the mouse position of that click. Then you can access the right piece by

```
x, y = square_clicked[x], square_clicked[y]    
piece = board[x][y]
```

Answer (score -1):

tkinter is not good at games such as chess since it is made for normal UI's, not games, i reccomend you to use `pygame`, here is a tutorial link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6xMBig-pP4&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-lp3jAExUCewBfMx3UZFkh5.